# How to Set SharePoint to use two alwaysOn AG?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

SQL1

- AG1 (Primary)
- AG2 (Secondary)
  *Listener (SPWeb)

SQl2

- AG1 (Secondary)
- AG2 (Primary)
  *Listener (SPApp)

Web Server (Content DB) should use AG1, App Server (Search DB) should use AG2.

How to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy and straight forward if you use single AG for a farm as I think you are creating2 AG on same sql server.

But to configure the Separate AG for content and separate for service and config, you need aliases for both AG sql.

When you create a farm give listener  for the service AG server, and after that when you configure the search then provide same.

At the time of content db you have to point it to 2nd AG listener which for content AG.

Updated after Guru,s(Trevor) advice.

Comment: No, don't use SQL Aliases. There's zero reason to be doing so with AGs. You simply point your connection string at the listener.

Comment: You are saying no need alias which point to listener? Really that is what we get from msft. I miss the listener from my answer....

Comment: Yes but based on your history, you've received bad advice numerous times from your PFE(s). Working at Microsoft, we never used SQL Aliases for AGs. Only the AG Listener itself. The point of a SQL Alias, in a 'standard' setup, is for SQL Server mobility -- that's it. With an AG, you automatically have that mobility. Moving SQL Servers? Add it to the AG, then failover dbs, etc.

Comment: Iol, but it's not even pfe....pla also did same...

Comment: MCS explains a lot for the advice you got :-)

Comment: Next I ll quote your blog n advice... We have meeting with them near future...:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41289/discussion-between-trevor-seward-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a single SQL Server at a time within an AG as read/write. This will reduce your patch window time (patch Server2, failover, patch Server1, and you're done, versus taking another failover).

You can create separate AGs and leverage them, just point SharePoint at the AG Listener FQDN for each AG. Each listener will have a unique port number, of course.

Comment: Listerner FQDN is  SPWeb.abc.com and SPApp.abc.com.

i dont know how point search database  to SPApp.abc.com ?

Comment: When you create your Search databases (or Search Service Application), you point the databases at the different listener. That's about it (just specify the `-DatabaseServer` parameter with the Listener FQDN).

Comment: I use SharePoint 2016, can not found any database location field. please give me a detail step

Comment: Use PowerShell to provision Search. You'll be able to specify it there.